# HtmlWeb User Agent

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, html-agility-pack, user-agent

I am using HtmlAgilityPack to grab a table from a web page.

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("http://test.com");
```

I am aware that HtmlWeb has a UserAgent property, however I have no idea how I am supposed to attach a user agent to the header of the httprequest.

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb().UserAgent("asdf");
```

returns the error

```
Error   1   Non-invocable member 'HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlWeb.UserAgent' cannot be used like a method.
```

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/discussions HtmlAgilityPack support discussions appear as simply questions, but nobody on the other end to respond.

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/documentation There is NO documentation here yet.

http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/downloads/get/437942 Tried downloading the documentation, to find that the chm file seems broken... I'm getting a Navigation to the webpage was cancelled error when I try to open anything within the chm documentation.

Comment: You can always use `WebRequest` and load the string to the HAP from it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just set the `UserAgent` property of the `HtmlWeb` object after instantiating it.

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
web.UserAgent = "your useragent string here";
```

Answer (score 3):

*HtmlWeb.UserAgent* is a property, not a method. Its Intellisense summary is:

> Gets or Sets the User Agent HTTP 1.1 header sent on any webrequest

Try something like:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
web.UserAgent = "asdf"; // Replace this with your actual user agent :)
```

Answer (score 1):

UserAgent is the property of HtmlWeb. You can use it this way:

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
web.UserAgent = "[user agent string here]";
```