# How to use HtmlAgilityPack in C#

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

CASE 1 :

I know by using 'HtmlAgilityPack' we can read the html content but in my scenario while I'm executing the URL("https://www.nseindia.com/reports/gsm") in this `doc = web.Load(URL);` line it is throwing the Error

Error is :

```
System.Net.WebException: 'The operation has timed out'
```

My code is :

```
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExtractHref("https://www.nseindia.com/reports/gsm");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        static void ExtractHref(string URL)
        {
            // declaring & loading dom
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol =
                          SecurityProtocolType.Tls | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc = web.Load(URL);

            // extracting all links
            foreach (HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
            {
                HtmlAttribute att = link.Attributes["href"];

                if (att.Value.Contains("a"))
                {
                    // showing output
                    Console.WriteLine(att.Value);
                }
            }
        }
```

Note : I tested with different web sites or url links (ex: https://www.google.com/ , https://en-gb.facebook.com/ ) in this scenario I didn't get any king of error's

I'm new to work with this HtmlAgilityPack.

suggest me why this error is coming `System.Net.WebException: 'The operation has timed out'`.

CASE 2 :

This line code is used to download the files which are available in the link "https://static.nseindia.com//s3fs-public/inline-files/contract_mas_illiquid_sec_12072021.xlsx"

```
webClient.DownloadFile("https://static.nseindia.com//s3fs-public/inline-files/contract_mas_illiquid_sec_12072021.xlsx", "Test.xlsx");
```

In this scenario also I'm getting the same error like `System.Net.WebException: 'The operation has timed out'`.

Here I'm getting that xlsx download file link from "https://www.nseindia.com/regulations/periodic-call-auction-illiquid-securities"  {using `Inspect` option} but I'm not able to downloading that excel file throw the coding.

Give me your best suggestions to achieve this two cases.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712537/htmlweb-user-agent

Comment: @Martheen, actually that is not my solution my issue is the page is not loading while it is loading at this line code `doc = web.Load(URL);` taking 1 to 2 mins time and saying `System.Net.WebException: 'The operation has timed out'`. Can you help me out from this ?

Comment: Have you tried it? I suspect that the site attempts to avoid scraper by detecting user agents.